# Burn NEP-141 tokens

Tags: rust, blockchain, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

I want to implement the `_burn(address account, uint256 amount)` function provided by [OpenZepplin's ERC20 library](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/token/erc20#ERC20-_burn-address-uint256-). The smart contract will call this function when some condition is true.

The Rust [fungible token example](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/9af51b8272ceb84319d54c36a64acdf11a61ca20/examples/fungible-token/ft/src/lib.rs#L90) has a `on_tokens_burned()` function, but it looks like a logger.

```rs
    fn on_tokens_burned(&mut self, account_id: AccountId, amount: Balance) {
        log!("Account @{} burned {}", account_id, amount);
    }
```

How to burn tokens of a particular user?

Comment: @LucioM.Tato I am able to burn using `self.token.accounts.insert(&user_account, &new_balance)`. Thought that there was a helper function in the spec, since a `on_tokens_burned()` was provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some implementation of burn:

```rust
    pub fn burn(&mut self, amount: U128String){
        let balance = self.internal_unwrap_balance_of(env::predecessor_account_id());
        assert!(balance>=amount);
        self.internal_update_account(&env::predecessor_account_id(), balance - amount);
        assert!(self.total_supply>=amount);
        self.total_supply -= amount;
    }

    /// Inner method to save the given account for a given account ID.
    /// If the account balance is 0, the account is deleted instead to release storage.
    pub fn internal_update_account(&mut self, account_id: &AccountId, balance: u128) {
        if balance == 0 {
            self.accounts.remove(account_id);
        } else {
            self.accounts.insert(account_id, &balance); //insert_or_update
        }
    }

    pub fn internal_unwrap_balance_of(&self, account_id: &AccountId) -> Balance {
        match self.accounts.get(&account_id) {
            Some(balance) => balance,
            None => 0,
        }
    }
```

we're using something similar here: https://github.com/alpha-fi/cheddar/blob/master/cheddar/src/internal.rs